# Display tooltip and receive focus inside tooltip

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a requirement where I need to show some buttons next to a dropdown by using a popup or a tooltip. For example, adding the buttons to the Contnet of the tooltip and displaying it when the user hovers the mouse over the dropdown.

However tooltip only stays open only while the mouse pointer is over the dropdown. So if I set the tooltip, and add 2 buttons to it, the user will not get a chance to click on the buttons inside the tooltip, since he has to move the mouse away from the dropdown for doing it, and while doing that the tooltip disappears.

Is there a way to keep the tooltip open for a certain duration of time, even after the user moves his mouse away from the dropdown, and ideally keep the tooltip open as long as the tooltip recieves focus?

Code:

```
<Style x:Key="ToolTipStyle" TargetType="ToolTip">
            <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Right"/>
        </Style>

      <ToolTip x:Key="YourToolTip" Style="{StaticResource ToolTipStyle}">
        <StackPanel Background="Yellow" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Yes"/>
            <Button Content="No"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ToolTip>

        <Style x:Key="DropDownStyle" TargetType="Controls:RadComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{StaticResource YourToolTip}"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay" Value="1000"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="2000"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.BetweenShowDelay" Value="10000"/>
        </Style>

 <Controls:RadComboBox x:Name="mydropDown"  Style="{StaticResource DropDownStyle}" ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyItems}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100">

        </Controls:RadComboBox>
```

Note:I'm using .NET 3.5

EDIT: A popup control is also fine, however the original question remains, how to click a button inside the popup, when the dropdown no longer has focus (under the assumption that the popup's IsOpen is binded to IsMouseOver property).

Thanks,
-Mike

Comment: Why not use System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup class?

Comment: If you want it to persist when the mouse is not longer over then look to a design that is not bound to IsMouseOver.

Answer (score 2):

If these buttons must appear every time a user goes near the combobox, then its probably the wrong UI paradigm to use a floating popup or tooltip and the buttons should probably be added to the toolbar where the combobox is, or retemplate the combobox and add the buttons (although that will likely be clunky also).

If you only need to show the buttons when a particular set of values in the model are set, then consider adding a tiny canvas in a corner of the page or user control so its z-order is above other controls and draw you own tool tip in there, with buttons etc. Then animate the opacity triggered by value on the model. I think when the opacity is 0, the item will not be clickable and get in the way of other controls.

You can wrap all that in a UserControl. Items in a Canvas are not clipped, which is why this works. I've written custom pop-up context menu controls in this way, by artificially injecting the canvas into the visual tree at runtime (sort of like AJAX).

Alternatively, you can do a similar thing by subclassing the combobox control, adding the properties to bind the buttons against and text etc., adding the canvas etc. to a new custom template and using the parts and states to bring it in and out of view. This route is best when you need to reuse this control over and over.

In short, I don't think its easy and it sounds like you can save the effort by reconsidering the design.